# Qt5 & RPi 2 -> "failed to add service - already in use?"

Tags: boot, pi-2

I have `gpu_mem_1024=512` in the `config.txt` file on my Raspberry Pi 2. However it doesn't boot anymore. Is only boots if I put `gpu_mem=16` in the `config.txt`.

However, when I try to run a QT app, with this memory split, the following error comes: "failed to add service - already in use?" Someone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You may want to add some details as per my comment on your deleted post.

Comment: I'm building a linux embedded system from the scratch for my RPi 2 using Buildroot. My teacher told me to put gpu_mem=16 in config.txt file. With this memory split, RPi boots and everything works fine but i can't run a Qt app that i'm developing. After some search on the internet, i've found that I must give more memory for GPU so I deleted "gpu_mem=16" and replace it with "gpu_mem_1024=512". However, after this RPi doesn't boot anymore.

Comment: I think you have gone from one extreme to the other, `gpu_mem=16` is the smallest I think you can allocate for the GPU, on the other hand the RPi 2 only has "1024" in total so perhaps with 512MB allocated for the GPU you have not enough memory for the Qt application to run on the 512MBytes you have left for the CPU...!